# Expanding Search Off Click Close JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made an expanding JQuery Search Box yesterday, which works like a charm! But, I am having trouble creating a script that makes it so when the user clicks off the search box, it closes.

This is my JQuery:

```
function expandSearch(){
                $('#search-input').toggleClass('search-input-open');
         }
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="navigation-search ngen-search">
    <form class="ngen-search-form form-search" action="search" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="q" id="search-input" class="form-search-input" placeholder="Search for games..." dir="ltr">
        <span onclick="expandSearch()" class="form-search-submit" value="&#x1f50e;">&#x1f50e;</span>
    </form>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.ngen-search{
    padding:0px 0px 0px;
}
.form-search-input{
    width:0px;
    height:55px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size:21px; 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #151515;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.search-input-open{
    width:410px !important;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px !important;
    display: initial !important;
}
.form-search-submit{
    display:inline-block;
    width:55px;
    height:43px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background-color:#151515;
    font-size:21px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:center;
}
```

All help is appreciated! Thanks!

Also, please note that I am quite new to JQuery and rarely use it.

Comment: Have you tried using .on('focusout', function(e) { //close stuff// });?

Comment: Would you be able to use an example in the JQuery code? @Araymer Thanks

Comment: Just add an additional jquery function $('#searchInput').on('focusout', function(e) { //close the box with css or whatever// });

It wouldn't need to go in your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a click handler which listens to the click on anywhere in the page and then remove the class like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#search-trigger').click(function() {
    $('#search-input').toggleClass('search-input-open');
  });

  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.ngen-search-form').length) {
      $('#search-input').removeClass('search-input-open');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.ngen-search {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px;
}
.form-search-input {
  width: 0px;
  height: 55px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: #151515;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.search-input-open {
  width: 410px !important;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px !important;
  display: initial !important;
}
.form-search-submit {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 55px;
  height: 43px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #151515;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation-search ngen-search">
  <form class="ngen-search-form form-search" action="search" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" id="search-input" class="form-search-input" placeholder="Search for games..." dir="ltr">
    <span id="search-trigger" class="form-search-submit" value="&#x1f50e;">&#x1f50e;</span>
  </form>
</div>
```